# How to put a dynamic background image into a FrameLayout

Tags: android, image, layout, dynamic, background

I want to thank you in advance. I'm new making Android apps (in fact this is my first Android app). In the app I let the users choose one of his/hers photos and put it like a background. I gather up the image and send it to the proper Activity using putExtra method.

This is how I process the image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0){
             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             InputStream is;
             try {
                 is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                 Bitmap imagen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                 final float densityMultiplier = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

                 int h= (int) (100*densityMultiplier);
                 int w= (int) (h * imagen.getWidth()/((double) imagen.getHeight()));
                 imagen=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imagen, w, h, true);

                 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);   
                 byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 

                 imagenCodificada = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

             } 
             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        }
    }
```

And this is how I send it:

```
i.putExtra("Preferencia5", imagenCodificada)
```

In the activity I decodified the image as a Bitmap but I don't know how to put it as a background into my FrameLayout.

In the Activity:

```
  byte[] b = Base64.decode(imagen, Base64.DEFAULT);
  Bitmap imDecodificada = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
```

And this is the starting of my layout's .xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use layout.setBackgroundDrawable with BitmapDrawable parameter

Comment: Hi pskink, but I have a question (really silly in fact) how I get the variable "layout"? Thank you

Comment: findViewById(R.id.framelayout)

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works perfect ^_^. I have another question, I know it's not the thread's topic but, Do you know how to get the user's phone background and put it into the activity background? Thank you so much.

Comment: there is no such thing  like "user's phone background" since every user can has different home launcher app